# How to work with stdClass Object in php?

Tags: php

I new in php.
Try parse a stdClass Object:

```
        $datastoresArray = $geoserver->listDataStores($item->name);
        foreach ($datastoresArray as $dstores){
            if($dstores->dataStore != null){
                $dstore = $dstores->dataStore;
                foreach ($dstore as $item){
                    echo "  - ".$item->name."\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

In this line `if($dstores->dataStore != null){` i get error `Traing to get property of non-object`. Becouse somethimes i not have a `dataStore` in `$dstores`. How to know what i have `dataStore` and whan dont have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
if(!empty($dstores->dataStore))
```

or

```
if(isset($dstores->dataStore))
```